# Can a nested Group By be done in a single Select?

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, grouping

Using T-SQL (we're on 2008, but if it can be done in 2012 using some new function/extension, please note)

This is purely out of curiosity...I ended up just going with a GROUP BY within a GROUP BY. But I'm curious to see if there is a way to do this in a **single** query, maybe there's some fancy shmancy functions or extensions I haven't learned yet....It's more of a challenge than it is a need to get the job done, as it's already done.

I tried building an example table on here, but it's too large to build, so here's the concept. The table has three columns, UserID, UserGroupID and Minutes. In one hour increments, we log how much time a user spends within an application. So, for example, UserID 1 spent 10 min during the hour of 04/28/2014 10:00:00, and then 15 minutes during the hour of 04/28/2014 11:00:00...and so on. (for this example, please ignore any time constraints as far as per day or per month, etc)

I wanted to see the **number of users** per group that have used the application for at least 30 minutes. This is the logic that was used:

```
SELECT UserGroupID, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT UserGroupID, UserID
    FROM Example
    GROUP BY UserGroupID, UserID
    HAVING SUM([Minutes]) >= 30
) AS x
GROUP BY UserGroupID
```

The question is, can this be done in a single query? Not looking for efficiency here, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but a negative is quite hard to prove.

The following query (without the `having` clause) can be simplified.  So:

```
SELECT UserGroupID, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT UserGroupID, UserID
    FROM Example
    GROUP BY UserGroupID, UserID
) AS x
GROUP BY UserGroupID;
```

Is pretty much the same as:

```
SELECT UserGroupId, COUNT(DISTINCT UserId)
FROM Example
GROUP BY UserGroupId;
```

(These are not exactly equivalent if `UserId` can be `NULL`, but that case could also be handled.)

I don't think there is a way to do your full query, though.  You need to aggregate by `UserGroupId, UserId` to get the `sum()` condition.  Then you need to aggregate just by `UserGroupId`.  Nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I stared at it for a while. I kept getting the feeling that there has to be a way to do it, but I went through every variation of the code I could, and couldn't come up with anything.

SQL has things like GROUP BY (WITH ROLLUP, CUBE and GROUPING SETS) which basically multiply your group by, I was hoping they would have something that did the opposite and allowed you to do a double group by...if that makes sense.